# MULTIPLE Rlm servers in one system. We are getting error as below

Tags: server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4nnh.png)

error in RLM servers. how to get it fix the same. attached screen grab for refernce.

09/25 19:41 (rlm) Web server starting on port 1111
09/25 19:41 (rlm) Using TCP/IP port 5061
09/25 19:41 (rlm) ... error binding UDP port 5053, port in use
09/25 19:41 (rlm)   This is probably due to another copy of RLM running
09/25 19:41 (rlm)   While not fatal, this instance of RLM won't respond
09/25 19:41 (rlm)   to broadcast requests.
09/25 19:41 (rlm) Starting ISV server genarts on port 51050
09/25 19:41 (rlm) New thread created to watch ISV genarts
09/25 19:42 (genarts) RLM License Server Version 14.1BL1 for ISV "genarts"
09/25 19:42 (genarts) Settings from RLM Version 11.0BL2 for ISV "genarts"
09/25 19:42 (genarts) Server architecture: x64_w4